# Stop Mozilla Firefox opening popups in a new tab

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am building a site which when you click a link it opens up two things; it opens up a pop-up and an external website in a new tab. This is so the user can interact with the pop-up whilst he/she browses the external webpage.

This was working fine for me but I think when my FF updated to version 15.0.1 on OSX lion, I can no longer get this to behave the way I want it to.

I have even changed the settings in FF: FF->Preferences->Tabs->Open new window in Tab instead to off and with no such luck.

I have also noticed that facebook connect on any site will open a new tab rather than a new pop-up too.

I can't seem to find any documentation on the web stating that this is FF's native behavior, even in their changelog.

Here is my javascript trigger which I am certain all the parameters are correct:

```
popWin = window.open('http://somesite.com','myTargetWindowName','height=650,width=450,pageXOffset=900,pageYOffset=900,scrollbars=yes');
```

Comment: Do you want this setting on **your** firefox (if so that's a question for superuser) or also for the users of your site (which isn't possible) ?

Comment: Yeah, it would be great if I could get it for my users but how come its not possible?